# Webpack - Typescript cannot find file /node_modules/react/package.json

Tags: reactjs, webpack, typescript1.6

**UPDATE:**
It seems likely that it is a [TypeScript issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4445) after all, probably coming for [a PR merged earlier today](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4352).

---

I originally posted this to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues but was advised that this might not be a TypeScript bug.

I am using typescript@next with webpack and ts-loader.

When running Webpack I am receiving the following error from typescript.js:43445

```
C:\Users\Michael\Development\Replicate>webpack
Using config file at C:\Users\Michael\Development\Replicate\tsconfig.json
C:\Users\Michael\Development\Replicate\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:43445
                throw new Error("Could not find file: '" + fileName + "'.");
                      ^
Error: Could not find file: 'C:/Users/Michael/Development/Replicate/node_modules/react/package.json'.
    at getValidSourceFile (C:\Users\Michael\Development\Replicate\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:43445:23)
    at Object.getSyntacticDiagnostics (C:\Users\Michael\Development\Replicate\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:43615:52)
    at C:\Users\Michael\Development\Replicate\node_modules\ts-loader\index.js:186:42
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Michael\Development\Replicate\node_modules\ts-loader\index.js:185:14)
    at Compiler.applyPlugins (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:26:37)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:193:12)
    at Compiler.emitRecords (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:282:37)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:187:11)
    at C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:275:11
    at Compiler.applyPluginsAsync (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:60:69)
    at Compiler.afterEmit (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:272:8)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:267:14)
    at C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:52:16
    at done (C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:248:21)
    at C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:44:16
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "Replicate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Reproducing typescript file not found bug",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Michael Ross",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.13.3",
    "ts-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "typescript": "^1.6.0-dev.20150825"
  }
}
```

my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./app.tsx",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ["", ".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.ts(x?)$/, loader: "ts-loader" }
        ]
    }
}
```

my app.tsx

```
import React = require('react');

class Demo extends React.Component<any, any> {
    render() {
        return <div>Trying to replicate</div>
    }
}

React.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById("demo"));
```

and just in case, my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "jsx": "react",
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "files": [
        "./typings/tsd.d.ts",
        "./app.tsx"
    ]
}
```

and tsd.json

```
{
  "version": "v4",
  "repo": "borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped",
  "ref": "master",
  "path": "typings",
  "bundle": "typings/tsd.d.ts",
  "installed": {
    "react/react.d.ts": {
      "commit": "71a7d5306ae4f9893aafd2d85d38aac8789ebf33"
    }
  }
}
```

If I have a configuration error, help and guidance is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
import React = require('react');
```

To:

```
var React = require('react');
```

Unless your going for the es6 way which should be:

```
import React from "react";
```

That could be the problem.

Comment: I also tried this as well, but it made no difference. This issue has been marked as a bug in TypeScript (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4445)

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been marked as a TypeScript bug for Milestone 1.6 https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4445